# Xamarin styles doesn't work - xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, styles

my Application is always with a white screen if I use style. 
When I debugged I found out it doesn't leave the line

```
InitializeComponent();
```

that is in the app xaml cs

it builds, but after gets white screen forever.

this is my app xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.App">
<Application.Resources>

    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:key="BackButton">Black</Color>

        <Style x:Key="button" TargetType ="but">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource BackButton}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 11:14. Type but not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms occurred

Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such type `but`...

Replace `TargetType ="but"` with `TargetType="Button"`, and everything should work fine.

And BTW, looking at your code, it's a good habit to adopt strict naming rules, in this way you don't mix out lower/upper casing or key names. I say this because the key of your color is pascal-case, while the button's is in lower-case.
You should also use more specific keys, not just `button`, but I believe this was just for the example.